# HTML encoding in profile for badge description

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

The Android app is showing the HTML encoded version of the badge description in the profile feed.

This is on version 1.0.6 on Samsung Galaxy SIII running Android 4.1.2.

[image: Android screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this! I had completely neglected to check if badges had HTML entities in them or not. This is fixed as of version 1.0.7.

Comment: I was about to report the same thing: saw it in 1.0.15 and 1.0.17

Comment: @127.0.9.6 In what section of the app?

Comment: In my profile, recent activities. Here is a [screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/bQydq.jpg) from version 1.0.17.

Comment: [not fixed yet](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225952/152859), or fix was somehow rolled back.