# Apostrophe not displaying properly

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

App version: 1.0.24

On a user's profile, the apostrophe isn't displayed properly, there are only two badges that have one in it (afaik).

[image]

Comment: Bug was fixed but returned: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/219747/152859

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, this is for SURE fixed now - out in version:  v1.0.25