# Something&#39;s wrong with titles for badges in recent achievements

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, top-bar

In the “Recent achievements” listing, apostrophes in question titles related to badges are apparently incorrectly escaped as decimal HTML character references, i.e. as `&#39;`:

[image: Screenshot]

This appears like a mix between [Something&#39;s wrong with the inbox message escaping](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/131807/188688) (for inbox) and [Apostrophe not displaying properly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225952/188688) (for badges). But both of these are marked as fixed for some time now, while I observed the described issue today.

The [Bug in HTML entities for badge notifications](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/242021/188688) (for `&ldquo;` and `&rdquo;`) might have the same underlying cause and is still active. Will drop a comment there, but leave this here as a separate question until someone can positively confirm that these two issues indeed have the same cause and can (and will) be fixed simultaneously.