# Where's my apostrophe?

Tags: bug, chat, display-names

My username has an apostrophe in it. I'm very proud of my apostrophe.

But today it suddenly stopped rendering in chat! My name is showing up everywhere as things like `Rand al&#39;Thor` or `Rand al&amp;#39;Thor`. It's just not as cool.

[image: WHERE'S MY APOSTROPHE?]

I can haz my apostrophe back? :-(

Comment: #ApostrophePride

Comment: I can't see the issue as there are no [FHCs.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/311398)

Comment: [Not a duplicate, btw.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225952/278659)

Comment: I don&amp;amp;#39;t see the problem.

Comment: This username looks nice. This shouldn&amp;amp;#39;t be solved ;)

Comment: Seems fixed now

Comment: I'm now tempted to edit Rand al'Thor's screen name to put the &#39 back in...

Comment: I have powers that make being an adult _really_ hard right now so I'm just going to up-vote this and close the tab. Nobody saw anything, can't prove a thing.

Comment: It's a good game, but I prefer 'Where's my cow?'

Comment: `.text()` -> `.html()`

Comment: Title Suggestion: "Where&#39;s my apostrophe?"